# AngularJS idiom for resetting a form field

Tags: angularjs

If I have a service that exposes an array of "selected" values (via 2 way databinding on a select2 widget), and I want to limit the length of this array to a maximum of 5 values, I can set up a `$scope.$watch` on the controller and if the new value from the select2 directive has a length longer than 5, set the selected list back to the old value (of 5).

This seems very messy. For a start it will mean calling `$scope.$watch` again needlessly, and also involves me having logic in the controller that I don't really want. As this is surely one of the main problems that angularJS was brought in to solve, is there not a better way to do this?

Update: the HTML for the widget I'm currently using

```
<input
  id="comparison"
  ui-select2="select2"
  ng-controller="MyController"
  ng-model="selected"
  placeholder="Select options (max 10)"
  >
</input>
```

Comment: This logic should be handled by the `select2` directive, or _a_ directive.

Comment: the directive is straight from the [ui-select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) lib. any pointers on how to go about extending the directive to do what I want?

Comment: You should use angular validation directives, to prevent adding to the select list if it reaches the maximum length (5 in this example), rather than trying to fix the array after it has.

Comment: I'm using angular version `1.2.14` and can't upgrade due to the requirement to support lower IE versions, so I can't use validation directives I don't think.

Comment: It is supported in version 1.2.14: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/guide/forms

Comment: Could you please add an answer showing what you mean? because from what I can tell none of those options will work, i've updated my answer to include the HTML for the widget.

Comment: After looking at it further I may have an understanding of what you meant, but if you could please update with an expanded answer anyway so I have something to accept that would be helpful, thx :)